# How to add multiple data in JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to add data from `JTextField` but if I pressed the process again, the data that I write is missing. Is there any solution for this code?

```
try{
    txttujuan.removeAll();
    int xxx=0;
    String XNilai,Nilai;
    for (xxx=0;xxx <jtable.getRowCount();xxx++){

        if (jtable.getValueAt(xxx,4).equals("1")){
            Nilai ="0"+ (String) jtable.getValueAt(xxx,2);   
            XNilai+=Nilai+",";       
        } else continue;     
        System.out.print(XNilai.substring(0,XNilai.lastIndexOf(",")));
        jtextfield.setText();
        jtextfield.setText(XNilai.substring(0,XNilai.lastIndexOf(",")));
        XNilai="";
    }

} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.print(e);
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me....

Comment: its working properly,, after iwant to add text into textfield its always refresh after i push the button, my data i've already wrote is missing

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 5):

> my data i've already wrote is missing

That is what the `setText()` method does. It replaces the existing text with the new text.

Instead of using a `JTextField` you can try using a `JTextArea`, then you can use the following to add text to the end:

```
textArea.append( "some text" );
```

If you really want to use a `JTextField` then you can use:

```
Document doc = textField.getDocument();
doc.insertString("some text", doc.getLength(), null);
```

to append text to the text field.